# Closing a window?

Tags: android, adb

I'm opening the connectivity settings on Android with the following command

```
adb shell am start -a android.settings.AIRPLANE_MODE_SETTINGS
```

Is there any way to close the window? That is, not just put it in the background, but properly close it (i.e. the equivalent of pressing the "X" button)

I have tried `force-stop`, `kill` and even `kill-all` but without success. I could find tons of pages explaining me how to open the window but none explaining how to close it

Comment: adb shell input keyevent DEL try this

Comment: @gowthamanM nothing happens, neither on screen, nor in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try sending `KEYCODE_BACK`, just alike one would manually do that:

```
adb shell input keyevent 4
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks